# json data into highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

For my project i want to use the json file below to show in the highcharts.
For some reason the chart stays empty.

i think i need to format the json part in someway but i cant seem the figure out how.
Im pretty new to this, so I hope someone can explain the code to me in a simple way.
how do i format the code below? I want to use the colum chart.

```
[

      {
        "stadsdeel":"A Centrum",
        "veiligheid":18994,
        "leefbaarheid":3822,
        "maatschappelijke integriteit":733,
        "totaal":23549
      },
      {
        "stadsdeel":"B Westpoort",
        "veiligheid":878,
        "leefbaarheid":318,
        "maatschappelijke integriteit":88,
        "totaal":1284
      },
      {
        "stadsdeel":"E West",
        "veiligheid":8648,
        "leefbaarheid":1672,
        "maatschappelijke integriteit":536,
        "totaal":10856
      },
      {
        "stadsdeel":"F Nieuw-West",
        "veiligheid":8673,
        "leefbaarheid":1832,
        "maatschappelijke integriteit":690,
        "totaal":11195
      },
      {
        "stadsdeel":"K Zuid",
        "veiligheid":10065,
        "leefbaarheid":2171,
        "maatschappelijke integriteit":767,
        "totaal":13003
      },
      {
        "stadsdeel":"M Oost",
        "veiligheid":8284,
        "leefbaarheid":1576,
        "maatschappelijke integriteit":511,
        "totaal":10371
      },
      {
        "stadsdeel":"N Noord",
        "veiligheid":5011,
        "leefbaarheid":1324,
        "maatschappelijke integriteit":385,
        "totaal":6720
      },
      {
        "stadsdeel":"T Zuidoost",
        "veiligheid":5031,
        "leefbaarheid":1264,
        "maatschappelijke integriteit":677,
        "totaal":6972
      },
      {
        "stadsdeel":"X onbekend",
        "veiligheid":196,
        "leefbaarheid":46,
        "maatschappelijke integriteit":26,
        "totaal":268
      },
      {
        "stadsdeel":"Amsterdam",
        "veiligheid":65780,
        "leefbaarheid":14025,
        "maatschappelijke integriteit":4413,
        "totaal":84218
      }
    ]

$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    $.getJSON('charts.json', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

});
```

Comment: If the above is the data you are going to give to build the chart it wont work, please go through the demos and js fiddle examples provided by highcharts, Also provide us what you have worked out that will help us to analyse your issue. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/ is the link for highchars demo

Answer (score 0):

Each point need to have y paramter with number value, becasuse highcharts use this param to calculate position of point.